# jQuery focus not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to focus on credit card validation fail. but strange `focus()` not working.

```
$('#cc_number').validateCreditCard(function (result) {
    if (result.length_valid && result.luhn_valid) {

    } else {
       $("#cc_number").focus();
       return false;
    }
});

<input  type="text" id='cc_number' name="cc_number" />
```

Comment: What's "not working"? I get an alert every time I blur the input.

Comment: only alert is working .. but why focus fail.. :(

Comment: The code in the fiddle you posted first contains the correct workaround for the problem :)

Comment: It's kind of annoying to force focus on an input until the user enters a valid value. I'd suggest you don't do it.

Comment: @dhsto ok i have remove alert message .. but why focus is not working for fail ..

Answer (score 58):

As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383747/jquery-focus-not-working/18383855#comment26996865_18383747), your original jsfiddle contains the solution.

A workaround is to put a timeout on the focus call.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#cc_number").focus();
}, 0);
```

I'm not 100% sure, but it could be that as the alert is called on blur, you're never actually allowing the textbox to lose focus, and therefore when focus is called, it already has it.

By using a timeout, you are putting the logic into a seperate thread, which runs seperate to the main javascript code (much like a callback function).

---

But as your question comments also mention, forcing focus until validation passes is annoying.

But this is more of a UX criticism.

Comment: @Richard I'm not 100% sure, but I believe it's because the focus is taken out of the current thread. The small timeout is irrelevant really, its just that the timeout doesn't run linear with the rest of the code, much like a callback function. Therefore I've amended the answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: It's because of timing of events.  If you set the focus within the Blur event, the input gains the focus.  However, because the blur event hasn't completed, it will lose focus as the event completes.  Adding the timeout allows the .focus() to occur after the blur event completes.  You also might be able to cancel the original event to have the same effect.

Comment: @Richard Thanks, very similar to what I have just edited my answer with

Comment: @Curt : ok fine your ans is also alternative solution of probelm. 
But frankly this is not a genuine solution..
This is JUGAAD as say in our local language ..

Comment: JavaScript is not multi-threaded: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: "By using a timeout, you are putting the logic into a seperate thread" is not correct. JS is not using threads. Doing `setTimeout(..., 0)` would also work.

Comment: Also, you can drop the second parameter `, 0)`. The default value is already `0`.

Comment: Why do you 2 ninjas enjoy criticizing people for irrelevant usage of words? So what if he mentioned threads: the intention of using that word is to emphasize that the code block is scheduled for delayed execution, and as such it is correct. Neither of you can spell "separate" correctly, though... Clutter boys...

Answer (score 17):

Your DOM may be getting refresh so focus is not working here. Instead you can follow this approach:

```
$('#cc_number').validateCreditCard(function (result) {
    if (result.length_valid && result.luhn_valid) {

   } else {
      $("#cc_number").attr("autofocus","autofocus")
      return false;
   }
});
```